# __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_react_dom___default.a.createPortal is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-dom

**The Error:**

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_react_dom___default.a.createPortal is not a function

Modal.js:14
  11 | 
  12 | 
  13 | function Modal(props) {
> 14 |   return ReactDOM.createPortal(JSX_MODAL, document.querySelector("#modal"));
  15 | }
  16 | 
  17 |
```

**The code:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const JSX_MODAL = (
  <div className="ui dimmer modals visible active">  
    <div className="ui standard modal visible active">
      THIS IS SOME TEXT IN THE MODAL // add some UI features here
    </div>
  </div>
);

function Modal(props) {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(JSX_MODAL, document.querySelector("#modal"));
}

export default Modal;
```

Which is called up in the render function on another component using `{Modal()}`.

**index.html (body section only):**

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div id="modal"></div>
</body>
```

**Dependencies:**

```
"react": "^16.8.6
"react-dom": "^16.0.0-alpha.13",
```

**Background:**

I am trying to use React portals to render content for a modal to it's own DOM node. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-render-modals-in-react-bbe9685e947e/), which basically presents a simplified proof of concept for what is presented in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).

**What I have tried:**

I could only find [one instance of people experiencing a similar issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11561), and they were able to resolve it by installing a version of React > 16.3.0. I am running React version 16.8.6.

Comment: Same, I'm using React 16.12.0 right now, and I got this error.

Comment: Huh, it seems to work. Here's my codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-portal-not-working-nhju5?file=/src/Modal.js

Comment: it seems to be working fine for me

Answer (score 17):

I had this error, though it was a simple fix.  I had stated:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react';
```

instead of:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Although it doesn't answer the original poster's issue, it may answer for future developers.

Answer (score 9):

I found this will work and no warnings in Chrome console:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import PortalReactDOM from 'react-dom'

//...

class Modal extends React.Component {
  //...

  render() {
    return PortalReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.el);
  }
}

//...
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(appRootEl);
root.render(<Parent />);
```

That is, use `react-dom` to `createPortal`, and use `react-dom/client` to `creatRoot`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case instead of using below:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client
```

changed to:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

and working now.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem but analyzing the problem we just have to import ReactDom from 'react-dom' itself.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
```

as

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

this works then

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, what I had was

```
import ReactDOM from "react";
```

Later, I changed it to

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

and the issue was resolved and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I use
`import PortalReactDOM from 'react-dom'`
instead of

```
`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`
```

and code looks like

```
const Loader = () => {
return PortalReactDOM.createPortal(
<div className="wrapper">
    <div className="loader">
        <img src={loaderImage} alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
</div>,
document.getElementById("loader")
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You might import this:-

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client

you have to change this import to this:-

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom

ANd then yur error will resolve